# react-reveal properties (Like zoom or Lightspeed) not working on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, scroll

Here is my Component code

```
import React from "react";
import { Zoom, LightSpeed } from "react-reveal";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Zoom>
          <p className="title">Truly Customizable Job Workflow</p>
        </Zoom>
      </div>
      <div className="commit">
        <LightSpeed left>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae
            assumenda placeat ab veritatis, iusto quaerat qui magni aliquam.
            Ipsum, aliquid fugit recusandae tenetur quo quod! Quas distinctio
            eius quod libero.
          </p>
        </LightSpeed>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

It's working fine. But only works once when I reload the window. I want to make it animate even on scroll. For example if I scroll down then scroll back up to that component I want to reanimate it. It only work once.

Comment: https://www.react-reveal.com/docs/when/ you probably want the when prop and some way to trigger it false when not visible. That should be as simple as detecting on scroll and setting the flag false in state when scrolling past it

Comment: @RobertMennell It is visible and working fine as I mentioned above. I want to reanimate it on scroll.

Comment: correct, but that is with the default set to true, which only works once. You need to force it to replay, and you do that by forcing that when state to true to show, and false to hide. Thus you need a way to trigger that. You can do that based on scroll position

Comment: Like I'm not so pro in React. Can you please share any source code?

Comment: this package would be a good place to start then: https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer